# SDDM & KDE Plasma DE not starting

Tags: kde, desktop-environments, plasma, sddm

I updated a while back and after rebooting I was greeted with a black screen because of no SDDM being started properly. Naturally I dropped to a virtual terminal session and starting troubleshooting. I reinstalled SDDM, Plasma & graphics driver, no change. I can load lightdm with startx but it has issues. I'm not familiar with the location of SDDM logs and how to get information from it, how do I proceed from here?

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem? I think I [may have the same problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091199/sddm-plasma-cannot-use-opengl-2-after-upgrading-to-18-04).